# java maven-compiler-plugin:3.1, javacTask: source release 1.7 requires target release 1.7

Tags: java, maven-compiler-plugin

I have a Java code that I want to build for Java 1.7.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <terget>1.7</terget>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But I receive the following error:

```
javacTask: source release 1.7 requires target release 1.7
```

The below debug outputs shows that target is 1.5:

```
-d C:\Users\przemekb\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ManagingPersistanceObjects\target\classes -classpath 
C:\Users\przemekb\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ManagingPersistanceObjects\target\classes;
C:\Users\przemekb\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\5.0.0.Final\hibernate-validator-5.0.0.Final.jar;
C:\Users\przemekb\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.1.0.Final\validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar;
C:\Users\przemekb\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.1.1.GA\jboss-logging-3.1.1.GA.jar;
C:\Users\przemekb\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\0.8.0\classmate-0.8.0.jar;
C:\Users\przemekb\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api\1.0.0.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar;
C:\Users\przemekb\.m2\repository\javax\persistence\persistence-api\1.0\persistence-api-1.0.jar;
C:\Users\przemekb\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\persistence\javax.persistence\2.1.0\javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar;
C:\Users\przemekb\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\persistence\eclipselink\2.5.1\eclipselink-2.5.1.jar;
C:\Users\przemekb\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\persistence\commonj.sdo\2.1.1\commonj.sdo-2.1.1.jar;
C:\Users\przemekb\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\persistence\org.eclipse.persistence.jpa\2.5.1\org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.5.1.jar;
C:\Users\przemekb\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\persistence\org.eclipse.persistence.asm\2.5.1\org.eclipse.persistence.asm-2.5.1.jar;
C:\Users\przemekb\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\persistence\org.eclipse.persistence.antlr\2.5.1\org.eclipse.persistence.antlr-2.5.1.jar;
C:\Users\przemekb\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\persistence\org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql\2.5.1\org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql-2.5.1.jar;
C:\Users\przemekb\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\persistence\org.eclipse.persistence.core\2.5.1\org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.5.1.jar;
C:\Users\przemekb\.m2\repository\org\apache\derby\derby\10.10.1.1\derby-10.10.1.1.jar;
C:\Users\przemekb\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\persistence\org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor\2.5.1\org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor-2.5.1.jar; -sourcepath 
C:\Users\przemekb\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ManagingPersistanceObjects\src\main\java; -s 
C:\Users\przemekb\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ManagingPersistanceObjects\target\generated-sources\annotations -g -nowarn -target 1.5 -source 1.7 -encoding UTF-8
```

How can I resolve this problem in NetBeans IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've spelt target wrong. It should be:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.7</source>
      <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 6):

Change your `terget` with `target` and *voilà* :)

With Apache Maven 3.x is possible to write this as plain `pom.xml` properties.

### More readable solution:

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have misspelled target - your element is named terget (not the second letter **e**).
Just replace it with target, and you'll be good to go:

```
<target>1.7</target>
```